# TABLE 1 with name and surname and TABLE 2 with two columns reference to names on TABLE 1

Tags: mysql, select

I'm not a programmer and I read alot from this form about how to solve my question, but my search was no good

I have two tables

TABLE 1: members

```
id*| name | surname
-------------------
1  | Joe  | Smith
2  | Mary | Sullivan
3  | Will | Stevenson
```

TABLE 2: messages

```
---------------------------------
id_message*| from | to | message
---------------------------------
       1   |   2  |  1 | test
       2   |   1  |  2 | re:test
       3   |   3  |  1 | hi
```

*auto-increment fields

I wish to do a query where lists all the messages as shown below:

```
Mary Sullivan  | Joe Smith     | test 
Joe Smith      | Mary Sullivan | re:test
Will Stevenson | Joe Smith     | hi
```

I'm really really really lost
Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: After 9993827492742934024 attemps, I managed do solve :)                                 
    
mysql_query("SELECT
M1.name AS name_from, 
M1.surname AS surname_from, 
M2.name AS name_to, 
M2.surname AS surname_to, 
M.*
FROM tz_members M1
INNER JOIN messages M ON M1.id = M.from
INNER JOIN members M2 ON M2.id = M.to")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `members` table 2 times with `messages`

```
select
concat(mem1.name,' ',mem1.surname) as `from_name`,
concat(mem2.name,' ',mem2.surname) as `to_name`,
m.message 
from messages m
join members mem1 on mem1.id = m.`from`
join members mem2 on mem2.id = m.`to`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select from1.name+" "+from1.surname, to2.name+" "+to2.surname, message from table2 
join table1 from1 on table2.`from` = table1.id
join table1 to2 on table2.`to` = table1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a Select with alias to refer members table 2 times:

```
SELECT CONCAT(M1.surname, ' ', M1.name) as FROM, CONCAT( M2.surname, ' ', M2.name) as TO FROM 
members M1 INNER JOIN 
messages M on M.from = M1.id 
INNER JOIN messages M2 on M.to = M2.id
```